# ARC GIS 10 + Google Maps API

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, google-maps-api, arcgis-rest-api

I am new to ArcGIS.

Is it possible to create a website that uses Google Map API but imagery from the ArcGIS 10 REST service?

Actually, I like the functionalities provided by the Google Map API like camera.

Is it possible to perform these operation using Google Map API on the imagery provided by REST service of ArcGIS 10.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize the [ArcGIS Extension to Google Maps API](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/webapi/javascript/gmaps/index.html) that ESRI provides.  As of right now though, it is based on v2 of the Google Maps API, with v3 hopefully coming sometime soon.

Answer (score 2):

Google Map API (v3) now supports SSL
http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/03/maps-apis-over-ssl-now-available-to-all.html

A good benefit with securing sensitive data

Technically v2 is deprecated

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html

> Note: The Google Maps Javascript API
>   Version 2 has been officially
>   deprecated as of May 19, 2010. The V2
>   API will continue to work as per our
>   deprecation policy, but we encourage
>   you to migrate your code to version 3
>   of the Maps Javascript API.

So ESRI should be moving over to v3 asap.
The major bonus with v3 is that it requires NO API KEY.
(though still lacks all the features of v2)